# Title: Creating a range of dates in format mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: pandas

Using pd.date_range  gives time stamps with dates in yyyy-mm-dd format and additional information in hours, mins etc. I want to go from here to a simple dataframe with a list of dates only in mm/dd/yyyy format only. I have tried converting things to strings, array of strings etc, modifying those , but it is all horribly convoluted.

Does anyone know of a  straightforward method? There must be one; this must be a common problem.

Edit/Addendum: Jason Dixon's reply hit the nail on the head. I had already tried all the other things some posters suggested. Thank you all.

Comment: did you try dt.strptime

Comment: Can you share some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few solutions possible, but I believe they will all involve Python string formatting.

Pandas will allow you to write a function - e.g., to convert a date to a string - and then apply that function to each row of a column. This feature uses the apply() function in Pandas.

Function to convert date to a string:

```
def convert_date_standard_string(datelike_object):

    """
    Return string version of date in format mm/dd/yyyy

    Parameters
    -----------

    datelike_object
        A value of type date, datetime, or Timestamp.

        (e.g., Python datetime.datetime, datetime.date,
        Pandas Timestamp)

    """

    return "{:%m/%d/%Y}".format(datelike_object)
```

Most of this function is documentation. The key part is `return "{:%m/%d/%Y}".format(datelike_object)`, which uses Python string formatting to put the date into the desired format.

Here is an example DataFrame with a column created from the date_range function.

```
>>> dates_list = pd.date_range(start="01/01/2019", end="01/31/2019")

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dates_list, columns=["Dates"])

>>> df

        Dates
0  2019-01-01
1  2019-01-02
2  2019-01-03
3  2019-01-04
4  2019-01-05
5  2019-01-06
6  2019-01-07
7  2019-01-08
8  2019-01-09
9  2019-01-10
10 2019-01-11
...
27 2019-01-28
28 2019-01-29
29 2019-01-30
30 2019-01-31
```

Note: Although the dates are **displayed** with only the year, month, and day, each value actually holds the time information also, as the OP pointed out. In addition, the format is not what the OP needs.

```
>>> df["Dates"].loc[0]
Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00')
```

Here is the syntax to apply the custom function created above to this column:

```
df["Dates"].apply(convert_date_standard_string)
```

Typically I would create a new column to store the converted values, like this:

```
>>> df["Dates - mm/dd/yyyy"] = df["Dates"].apply(convert_date_standard_string)

>>> df

        Dates Dates - mm/dd/yyyy
0  2019-01-01         01/01/2019
1  2019-01-02         01/02/2019
2  2019-01-03         01/03/2019
3  2019-01-04         01/04/2019
4  2019-01-05         01/05/2019
5  2019-01-06         01/06/2019
6  2019-01-07         01/07/2019
7  2019-01-08         01/08/2019
8  2019-01-09         01/09/2019
9  2019-01-10         01/10/2019
10 2019-01-11         01/11/2019
...
27 2019-01-28         01/28/2019
28 2019-01-29         01/29/2019
29 2019-01-30         01/30/2019
30 2019-01-31         01/31/2019
```

To demonstrate that the new column is a string:

```
>>> df["Dates - mm/dd/yyyy"].loc[0]
'01/01/2019'
>>> type(df["Dates - mm/dd/yyyy"].loc[0])
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: Jason, Your "convert_date_standard_string" is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a bunch. I had tried all other things suggested here. Thanks to the others who replied as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`dt.strftime()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) (with `'%m/%d/%Y'` pattern in your case) on your column containing `datetime64` entries. If they aren't of this format yet, try converting the column first by running [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) on it.